# Change WooCommerce default password security level

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, passwords, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to change the WooCommerce Registration form minimum password strength and I am unable to do much.

Can anyone please share a solution by which I can amend the minimum password strength and allow users to user a password that's 7 characters long and does not need any symbols or capital letters inside it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only existing hook setting for that is **`woocommerce_min_password_strength`** filter hook. So you can set a custom hook function and lowering this strenght. There is 4 possible settings:

- **`3`** => Strong (default)
- **`2`** => Medium
- **`1`** => Weak
- **`0`** => Very Weak (anything).

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_min_password_strength', 'reduce_min_strength_password_requirement' );
function reduce_min_strength_password_requirement( $strength ) {
    // 3 => Strong (default) | 2 => Medium | 1 => Weak | 0 => Very Weak (anything).
    return 2; 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

> All other solutions will be complicated and a real development.

Comment: thank you for your help. I used some javaascript to fix the issue since I needed to a very specific password criteria. thanks for your help!

Comment: @HusnainAbbas You should add an update to your question or directly as an answer with that code and some explanations. This will be useful for the community. Thanks.

Comment: Note: Contrary to the default hint verbiage, there is NOT a required number or type of characters that correspond to each security level. It is controlled by an open source, pattern-matching algorithm called 'zxcvbn' developed by Dropbox. Link: https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn

Answer (score 12):

The [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900628/264547) by @LoicTheAztec works perfectly and is very clear. I'm adding this answer because I'm not sure it's correct to put additional suggestions and code in a comment (sorry if I'm not following proper StackOverflow protocols -- someone please let me know if that's the case!).

Anyway even after changing the password strength requirement I was still seeing the very stern and rather unhelpful password hint demanding twelve characters &c., so I went looking for a way to change that. Here are the two functions I've got running and they're working just as expected.

For the password hint function, thanks to [arjenlentz](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13534#issuecomment-285539760).

```
// First, change the required password strength
add_filter( 'woocommerce_min_password_strength', 'reduce_min_strength_password_requirement' );
function reduce_min_strength_password_requirement( $strength ) {
    // 3 => Strong (default) | 2 => Medium | 1 => Weak | 0 => Very Weak (anything).
    return 2; 
}

// Second, change the wording of the password hint.
add_filter( 'password_hint', 'smarter_password_hint' );
function smarter_password_hint ( $hint ) {
    $hint = 'Hint: longer is stronger, and consider using a sequence of random words (ideally non-English).';
    return $hint;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, that code did not work for me to lower the password requirements. I tried a couple other codes but to no avail. I ended up using this code below to simply remove the password requirement check.

```
function iconic_remove_password_strength() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'iconic_remove_password_strength', 10 );
```

Taken from here: https://iconicwp.com/blog/disable-password-strength-meter-woocommerce/

Comment: Yes the meter was blocking me on the reset password page