# Wordpress/Woocommerce password minimum length

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, passwords

I have a webshop and I received a complaint about the minimum password length.
Its minimum length right now is 12 characters. I want to change that to 6 characters.

I know it's less safe but I know the risks. I searched through all my Wordpress files and databases but didn't find it.

Does anyone know how I can change it? (No plugins please.)

Comment: You can't change the length, but you can change the strength: [Change WooCommerce default password security level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899310/change-woocommerce-default-password-security-level/43900628#43900628)