# customize woocommerce password strength and change hint and error message

Tags: woocommerce, passwords, checkout

I want to have custom password strength for woocommerce checkout password field, 
It should be minimum 8 chars, 1 letter, 1 digit.

I have done this but message comes when user click on Place order, I want the message to appear when typing password, How to achieve this?

Comment: For pasword strength: [Change WooCommerce default password security level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899310/change-woocommerce-default-password-security-level/43900628#43900628)

Comment: Asking from developer view, I know the way to change strength number via functions, but have to do this customization. Please help.