# woocommerce_min_password_strength create_function deprecation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, deprecated

Found: Function create_function() is deprecated

The function is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_min_password_strength', create_function( '', 'return 1;' ) );
```

I converted it to:

```
function wooc_password_check($checks) {
    if($checks==="") { return 1; }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_min_password_strength', 'wooc_password_check' );
```

Is this correct or do I need to do this another way?

Comment: the answer given by @LoicTheAztec gives some more explanation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900628/11987538  
your 'checks' variable is actually 'strength', 
and therefore only contains an integer. 
In your code you will compare this as a string.

Comment: So I just change it to return 1 and change the checks to strength?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The number you choose depends on the strength you prefer when creating a password, as you could see with my already posted link. 3 => Strong (default) | 2 => Medium | 1 => Weak | 0 => Very Weak (anything).