# Woocommerce weak password checkbox (Storefront Child Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a password problem when registering a new customer on woocommerce. Every time a customer is going to create a password to access the store he needs at least 12 characters to create a password.

I know that WooCommerce does not have any hooks to reduce the number of required characters (from 12 to 8 or 6) and the only available hook that exists to reduce password security is `woocommerce_min_password_strength` like in [Change WooCommerce default password security level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899310/change-woocommerce-default-password-security-level/43900628#43900628) answer code.

instead of setting it to `return 0;` (Very weak) I know that on the `dashboard>user>edit` there is the checkbox option "Confirm use of weak password" (see below)

[image]

there is some way to enable this option on the registration and/or my-account page? So that the customer can confirm and be aware that their password is not secure enough. I know and I do not recommend reducing security of any kind, but this 12 character system discourages new users from creating an account within the website.

Comment: Have you tried with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991851/10447197

Comment: removing the password requirements worked, but I still need a little more security, I was thinking I could use this solution, copy `woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php`. to my child theme and add validation password with javascript to place some restrictions like password of up to 8 digits is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me solve this problem. You can remove the password strength using the solution indicated by @Vincenzo Di Gaetano link here: [stackoverflow.com/a/53991851/10447197](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899310/change-woocommerce-default-password-security-level/53991851#53991851)

removing the strength of the password the user can enter any type of password without any restriction, but a little restriction would be welcome to prevent users from creating very weak password.

So I found a very simple solution:

```
function remove_password_strength() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'remove_password_strength', 10 );
```

The code goes in your child theme's `functions.php`

create in your child theme folder `woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php` and copy the code of `form-login.php` from the `woocommerce` plugin

In `form-login.php` there is input:

`<input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />`

change the input to:

`<input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" />`

here the full code, you can copy and paste in your `form-login.php` in your child theme

```
<?php
/**
 * Login Form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 4.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

<div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

    <div class="u-column1 col-1">

<?php endif; ?>

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

    </div>

    <div class="u-column2 col-2">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>

                    //Insert input pattern here
                    <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" />
                </p>

            <?php else : ?>

                <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```